# How to fill a column in pandas dataframe based on some conditions set upon two different columns?

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a df like below:

```
 A     B    C
null   0   null
null   4   null
5      6   null
0      0    0
```

Now, I want to fill my column C based on Columns A & B condition being:
only if there is a null in column A against the '0' of column B then let column C be null otherwise in all other cases copy column B to column C. This means that I want my df to look like this:

```
 A     B    C
null   0   null
null   4    4
5      6    6
0      0    0
```

How can i achieve this in pandas?
Any help would be appreciated as I am quite new in python and pandas programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with conditions chained by `&` for bitwise AND:

```
import numpy as np

m1 = df.A.isna()
m2 = df.B.eq(0)
df['C'] = np.where(m1 & m2, np.nan, df.B)
print (df)
     A  B    C
0  NaN  0  NaN
1  NaN  4  4.0
2  5.0  6  6.0
3  0.0  0  0.0
```

Comment: maybe add `import numpy as np` since he's new to Python & pandas.good answer as always sir.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) + [`Series.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
df['C']=df['C'].fillna(df['B'].mask(df['B'].eq(0)))
print(df)

     A  B    C
0  NaN  0  NaN
1  NaN  4  4.0
2  5.0  6  6.0
3  0.0  0  0.0
```

---

or using [`Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html):

```
df['C']=df['B'].mask(df['B'].eq(0)).where(df['C'].isnull(),df['C'])
print(df)

     A  B    C
0  NaN  0  NaN
1  NaN  4  4.0
2  5.0  6  6.0
3  0.0  0  0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `fillna` and checking if `A + B > 0`, if so then fill `C` with `B` using `loc`:

```
mask = df['A'].fillna(0) + df['B'] > 0
df.loc[mask, 'C'] = df['B']
```

```
     A  B    C
0  NaN  0  NaN
1  NaN  4  4.0
2  5.0  6  6.0
3  0.0  0  0.0
```